# Patch outdated SQL query before SQL Server executes it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, runtime, patch

Running SQL Server 2005. A piece of software integrates with our database. Unfortunately they chose to make direct SQL queries instead of using stored procedures. Now we have changed our database scheme and the query in question is no longer valid.

Is it possible to patch T-SQL in runtime, on SQL Server?

E.g.
When SQL Server gets a `SELECT A FROM InvalidTable` for a specific database, the query would be converted to `SELECT A FROM ValidTable` just before it gets executed.

**Edit:**
This is the query in question:

`SELECT * FROM DataTable c JOIN Users u ON u.UserName = @P0 AND c.DepartmentID = b2.DepartmentID WHERE c.Status = 0` where `DepartmentID` has moved to another table!

Comment: You could create a view named `InvalidTable` that does `select NewColumnName as OldColumnName from ValidTable`

Comment: Consider using views to replace tables which went away. that way all the invalid SQL becomes valid due to existence of a view.

Comment: Hmm, choosing to use SQL (or Linq or whatever) instead of stored procedures is not necessarily unreasonable. My criticism would be of access to the database by an application over which you have no control/for which you don't have to the source which is what has caused the problem to arise. (I will assume that predates your involvement!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Views and Synonyms to hide schema changes.

So for simple things (like `InvalidTable` is now `ValidTable`), you can define a [synonym](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190626.aspx)

```
CREATE SYNONYM InvalidTable FOR CorrectSchema.ValidTable;
```

For more complex things (columns, JOINs, table splits, data types etc) you need a view

```
CREATE VIEW InvalidTable 
AS
SELECT 
   col1, col2, 
   CAST(col3 AS varchar(1000)) AS col3, -- fix data type
   1 AS col4  -- not used now, but expected in legacy calls
FROM
   CorrectSchema.ValidTable
WHERE
   col5 = 'Something'
GO
```

Edit, after OP realises they've bollixed themselves

You can't have a view or synonym if a table exists with the same name in the same database.

So, use another DB and make the legacy app use that instead. In the examples, you'd have DataTable in another db with the assumption you can use another DB withoout changing code

```
USE legacyDB
GO
CREATE VIEW DataTable
AS
SELECT
   *
FROM
   CorrectDB.CorrectSchema.ValidTable V
   JOIN
   CorrectDB.CorrectSchema.OtherTable O ON ...
GO
```

Otherwise, rename the correct DB and point all non-legacy code to the renamed DB.

Comment: Ah, +1 I like the `synonym` idea.  Didn't think of that.

Comment: @Shark: I've used this quite often to manage releases of code or table change. Also good for poor man's partition switching with ETL tasks

Comment: Good suggestion! But since a column was moved to another table, I don't think this will help. (Please see my updated post!)

Comment: @NOPslider: then you just use a view called DataTable to hide the JOIN to bring it back. If you still have DataTable then you've shot yourself in the foot...

Comment: I still have DataTable so I can't create the view :(

Comment: @NOPslider: if you can change the DB context of the legacy app you can use 2nd database to allow 2 objects and use 3 part names in the view. Will update answer

Comment: Regarding synonyms, keep in mind that they don't work with SqlDependency.

Comment: @gbn: Thanks a lot!! A secondary database did the trick! Also, thanks for pointing out the `SYNONYM` feature. Good to know!

Answer (score 4):

The only way I can think of is to use views to abstract the `ValidTable` names.  Something like:

```
create view InvalidTable
as

    select Col1, Col2, Col3, ColN
    from ValidTable

go
```

Depending on how many database objects are contained and the knowledge of which are valid/invalid, this would be a huge headache.

This is a bad situation you're in, and the first question I would ask is why are you changing the database schema of a 3rd party application's database?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this. (We didn't change their database scheme. We changed ours! We are trying to get an old integration to work without patching _their_ code...)